# How many mappings have an IFS?

Tags: fractals, iterated-function-system

In most of paper about iterated function systems and fractals which I read, an iterated function system is taken as finite set of contraction mappings like $\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}$. In some paper, the number of contraction mappings is taken as $n\geq2$.

Why is there a restriction about the number of contraction mappings in some paper?

Answer (score 4):

The restriction $n \ge 2$ excludes a trivial case. If $n=1$ then there is only a single contraction mapping, and then the fixed set

$$S = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f_i(S) = f_1(S)$$

is simply the (unique) fixed point of $f_1$, which is not very interesting.

Comment: Thank you @gandalf61. Is this unique fixed set actually only a point? Also, could this point be taken as fractal?

Comment: With some technical conditions, a contraction mapping has a single fixed point - this is the Banach fixed-point theorem. You could regard this point as being a fractal, but it is a very trivial fractal !